# How to keep Dialogflow conversation when user navigates through the website?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm sure this question will be a no-brainer for experienced users ;)

I'm developing a Dialogflow ES chatbot. I'm using Dialogflow Messenger integration (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger).

The embed code is pretty straightforward, so the bot is already running on a website.

The basic embed code looks something like this:

```xml
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
    <df-messenger
        chat-icon="icon.png"
        chat-title="Chat Title"
        intent="WELCOME"
        agent-id="[SOME HASH CODE]"
        language-code="en"
        expand
    ></df-messenger>
```

This basic embed code works in a way that whenever user reloads the page or goes to another page on the same domain, the bot gets expanded which is OK. But at the same time the bot/conversation is reset. I'm sure that this has something to do with the intent parameter with a value of "WELCOME" that is hard-coded in the embed code.

The case:

1. User comes to the website, chatbot expands, conversation begins and gets to the 3rd step of the conversation flow and user gets the appropriate response from the bot. For instance, the user gets two chips (Yes, No).
2. User navigates to another subpage and the bot expands again. Currently the bot is reset.

Question:
What do I have to do to keep the conversation flow even if user comes to another subpage? So instead of user in the second step above having to start the conversation all over again, he immediately gets those two chips (Yes, No)?

I tried this by removing the intent parameter in the second subpage embed code but in that case the bot expands and is just waiting for a user response (now it seems logical since it doesn't know the intent).

Thanks